# Subcategories not displaying in select menu

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have been messing around with subcategories and created a database new categories for testing purposes.

```
Table newcategories

category_id (int) AUTO
name (varchar) NOT NULL
parent (int) NULL
category_desc (text) NULL
sort_order (int) NOT NULL
```

I entered some categories and subcategories into the db but I have been having issues when trying to display main categories with corresponding sub categories in a select menu.

```
<?php
    // // // query database to return all existing main categories
    $selectMainCat='SELECT * 
                    FROM newcategories 
                    WHERE parent is NULL 
                    ORDER BY sort_order ASC';

    $smc=$conn->query($selectMainCat);
    while($rowsmc = $smc->fetch_assoc()) { 
        $parent_id = $rowsmc['category_id']; 
?>

        <optgroup label="<?php echo "{$rowsmc['name']}";?>">
        <option value="<?php echo"{$rowsmc['category_id']}"; ?>" 
<?php 
        if (isset($catID) && $catID=="{$rowsmc['category_id']}") 
            echo "selected";
?>
>
<?php 
            echo "{$rowsmc['name']}";?></option>
<?php
    // // // query database to return all sub categories
            $selectSubCat='SELECT * 
                           FROM newcategories 
                           WHERE parent = "$parent_id" ';

            $ssc=$conn->query($selectSubCat);
            while($rowssc = $ssc->fetch_assoc()){ 
?>
                <option value="<?php echo"{$rowssc['category_id']}"; ?>" 
<?php 
                if (isset($catID) && $catID=="{$rowssc['category_id']}") 
                    echo "selected";
?>
>
<?php 
                     echo "{$rowssc['name']}";?></option>
<?php
                }
?>
</optgroup>
<?php
            }
?>
```

Below is what I have entered into the db

```
category_id     name        parent  category_desc   sort_order
1               Fruits      NULL    NULL             1
2               Vegetables  NULL    NULL             2
3               Apple       1       NULL             1
4               Arugula     2       NULL             1
5               Cabbage     2       NULL             2
6               Honeycrisp  3       NULL             1
7               Braeburn    3       NULL             2
```

HTML OUTPUT

```
<select class="form-control m-b" name="catID" id="catID">
  <option value="" disabled selected> Select Main Category</option>
  <option value="" disabled></option>
  <optgroup label="Fruits">
    <option value="1" >Fruits</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Vegetables">
    <option value="2" >Vegetables</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: How can we be sure that you have set the subcategories up correctly in the database

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: **Have you** looked a the `page source` in your browser to see if this mess has caused some duff HTML to be generated, because I would say it probably has

Comment: @tadman I am not using $_POST or $_GET

Comment: @RiggsFolly not to concerned about the html output at this moment.

Comment: Well you should be as it looks like you might be outputing ??something for subcategories?? but if the HTML is invalid it is likely not showing up in the page

Comment: You can see my html output above.

Comment: @user3354780 At some point you're taking in user data. `$parent_id` should not be in the query, that should be a placeholder. That will also fix the problem where you're literally inserting `"$parent_id"`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have here is the value is not being interpolated correctly since you're using the [non-interpolating quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single). This can be fixed by doing the query correctly using placeholder values:

```
$ssc = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM newcategories WHERE parent=?');
$ssc->bind_param('i', $parent_id);
$result = $ssc->execute();

while ($rowssc = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
  ...
}
```

It's extremely risky to put data of any kind directly in a query, *especially* something that comes directly from the user via `$_GET`, `$_POST` or `$_REQUEST`. Even `$_COOKIE` and `$_SESSION` can be trouble since these may contain values previously supplied by a user, or which a user has some degree of control over.